# Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.boot.MappingNotFoundException: Mapping (RESOURCE) not found : allinone.hbm.xml : origin(allinone.hbm.xml)

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

**Main class**,DAO

```
package news.hib.Single;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration().configure("src2/hibernate.cfg.xml");
        SessionFactory sf = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
        Session ses = sf.openSession();
        Transaction t =ses.beginTransaction();
        Employee e = new Employee();
        e.setId(101);
        e.setName("bhanu");
        e.setMail("bp.com");
        Hardware h = new Hardware();
        h.setId(101);
        h.setName("bhanu");
        h.setMail("bp.com");
        h.setSkills("idk");
        Admin a = new  Admin();
        a.setId(101);
        a.setName("bhanu");
        a.setMail("bp.com");
        a.setSalary(199999);
        ses.save(e);
        ses.save(h);
        ses.save(a);
        t.commit();
        ses.close();
        System.out.println("success");
    }
}
```

**Employee class**,Bean class

package news.hib.Single;

```
import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorColumn;
import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorType;
import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorValue;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="Bubble")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="type",discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@DiscriminatorValue(value="emp")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String mail;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getMail() {
        return mail;
    }
    public void setMail(String mail) {
        this.mail = mail;
    }

}
```

**Admin class extends Employee**, Bean class

package news.hib.Single;

```
import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorValue;
import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value="admin")
public class Admin extends Employee{
    private double salary;
    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
    public void setSalary(double salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
}
```

**Hardware class extends Employee**,Bean class

package news.hib.Single;

```
import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorValue;
import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value="hard")
public class Hardware extends Employee{
    private String skills;
    public String getSkills() {
        return skills;
    }
    public void setSkills(String skills) {
        this.skills = skills;
    }    
}
```

**Hibernate-cfg file**,configuration file.

com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
            root
            jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database1
            root
            org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
            create
            true

**mapping-file**,i am trying to write a code for table per class approach.

**I got this exception**,any mistakes?

> Hello World!
>           Jul 18, 2017 4:20:07 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
>           INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.10.Final}
>           Jul 18, 2017 4:20:07 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment 
>           INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
>           Jul 18, 2017 4:20:08 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager
>   
>           INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
>           Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.boot.MappingNotFoundException: Mapping (RESOURCE) not
>   found : allinone.hbm.xml : origin(allinone.hbm.xml)
>             at org.hibernate.boot.spi.XmlMappingBinderAccess.bind(XmlMappingBinderAccess.java:56)
>             at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.addResource(MetadataSources.java:274)
>             at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.spi.MappingReference.apply(MappingReference.java:70)
>             at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:413)
>             at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
>             at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:691)
>             at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
>             at news.hib.Single.App.main(App.java:18)

Comment: where are you stored the allione.hbm.xml file?

Comment: @cralfaro,i have created 2 packages                                                                1)news.hib.Single->Employee.java ,Admin.java ,Hardware.java and App.java                                                                                                
2)src2-> allinone.hbm.xml and hibernate.cfg.xml ,

Comment: @cralfaro, i am getting same exception. I think problem is in hibernate.cfg.xml and mapping file

Comment: @cralfaro, i have created table like this ->create table bubbles(id int,discriminator varchar(20),name varchar(20),mail varchar(20),salary double,skills varchar(20));

Comment: But the problem is that your app is not able to find the hbm file, so doesnt know yet the table name, first you need to make accessible the hbm file from your main class. Modify the path to something is readable from your main class

Comment: wait i just saw you have a big confusion, you have declared the xml mappgin but also by annotations with entity and table, I would start from scratch with a tutorial based on annotations, will be easier

Comment: code formatting

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the full path to your hbm files. So need to add "src2"

```
<mapping resource="src2/allinone.hbm.xml"/>
```

Note: Your package name have an incorrect format:

> news.hib.Single

Should be all package names in lowercase.

Source [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-xmlconfig)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to keep the mapping xml in the same path as the hibernate configuration file and only mention the mapping file name in your  tag in the hibernate configuration file.

It worked for me.